# Identical float values comparing as inequal

Tags: c, floating-point

I was working on some 'determine the output' questions in C. I came across this question which looked simple on the face of it, but after running the code left me puzzled.

The output I expected was "True". However upon running, it was "False". And when I checked the value of f using printf(), it showed 0.1. Can someone please explain why f being assigned 0.1 doesn't return true for the IF statement?

There was no explanation for the answer from where I picked the question up, and I wasn't able to find an answer myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 0.1;
    if (f == 0.1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

Comment: Read about [floating point precision](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Going through it now @haccks, thanks.

Comment: Note that if you changed the type of `f` to `double` or compared to `1.0f` rather than `1.0`, the condition would be true.

Comment: @avakar I'm confounded by how many people are answering this, yet *not* pointing out that the literal `0.1` isn't a `float`, its a `double`. The *loss* of precision when converting a floating point value that cannot be represented perfectly as `double` or `float` from `double` *to* `float` is causing the results seen.

Comment: @WhozCraig, hopefully, Vlad's answer will `float` to the top.

Comment: The proposed dup doesn't answer _this_ question. The problem of adding floating point numbers of **the same type** in a loop, is quite different from comparing floating point numbers of **different types**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that variable `f` defined as having type `float` while float constant `0.1` has type `double`. Type `double` has more precision than type `float`. it has more binary digits to represent fraction. So in this statement

```
        float f = 0.1;
```

there is a truncation.

To get the expected result you should write at least

```
        if (f == 0.1f)
```

Also that to be sure that there is no rounding the code should look as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    float f = 0.1f;

    if ( f == 0.1f )
        printf("True\n");
    else
        printf("False\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 Type consistency; its whats for dinner.

Comment: I see. Need to go back to the absolute basics! Thanks so much for the explanation, it all makes sense now. :)

Comment: So, can it be deduced that the compiler takes numbers as double unless explicitly specified as float?

Comment: @user3714817 Yes. Just like literal `5` is an `int` unless you specify otherwise (`5l` for `long int`, `5u` for `unsigned int`, etc), there has to be a default *somewhere*. For floating pointer literals the default is `double` unless you specify otherwise with the literal value itself (in this case the `f` specifier in this example).

Comment: @user3714817 btw, to firm this up once in for all, just throw out everything but the `if` test and change that expression to `if (0.1f == 0.1)`. The result (False) should endure.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, it'll be easier to remember this now that I know the defaults better!

Comment: "So in this statement `float f = 0.1;` there is a truncation" is _likely_ true as most floating point implementations use a binary based format, `0.1` is not exactly representation as such and `double` format often differs from `float`. C does not specify floating point must be binary base and decimal base floating point, though rare, could represent `0.1` equally both as a `float` and `double`. More common are limited systems (embedded) that use the same floating point representation for both `float` and `double`, so `0.1f == 0.1` is true. C doesn't require `double` and `float` to differ.

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the precision of float value.

Check this:- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

You can better use double instead of float.

Also to note that(*Correctly pointed by WhozCraig*) that 0.1 is a double not a float. Change the `float` to `double` and you will get the expected output.

Comment: It's quite silly how even upon printing the variable, it doesn't reflect the actual precision it used to make the comparison!

Comment: @user3714817: Probably you didn't print with enough precision?

Answer (score 1):

`0.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary . `0.1` in binary would be `0.0r0011r` which is recurring so internally it is rounded off which is not exact value. That is why it returns false. But if you try with number like 0.5 which is `0.1` in binary or 0.250 or 0.125 whichever can be perfectly represented it would return true. Also read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html . Better to use `double` for more accurate results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the 0.5 example!

Comment: Sure it can't be represented exactly, but `0.1` doesn't magically change its representation. The only reason the comparison doesn't work is because `0.1` as a `double` has a different representation than the `float` it's being compared to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a problem float type has. Check that if you change float with double type it prints true instead of false. Also try this output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f;
    for(f=.0;f<10.;f+=0.1)
        printf("%f \n",f);    
}
```

Comment: `double` has the same problem in general. Changing `0.1` to `0.1f` also works because the same value is compared to. If using `double`, `0.1` is a `double` and thus the same value is compared to.

Comment: yes indeed, but using double you will have less problems like this.

Comment: Less problems where you explicitly have two constants to compare. Nothing is ever that simple when you actually *use* floating-point numbers. You have no idea what the exact number being given to you to compare is and trying to compare it as if you do will not give you good results, whether you use `float` or `double`.