# Comparison two values from two different classes "<class 'pydicom.valuerep.DSfloat'>" and <class 'numpy.ndarray'> in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pydicom

I want to compare some values using "if" in the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
if Slice_num[person][i, [1]] == Z_pos:   # Slice_num[0][15, [1]] is ['-10.000000'] and Z_pos = -10.000000 
    absname = os.path.join(root, dcmfile)
```

---

Example: Values in the above variables are equal:

```
Z_pos: -10.000000 , <class 'pydicom.valuerep.DSfloat'>
Slice_num[person][i, [1]]: ['-10.000000'] , <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So, when the code is performed, `if`statement cannot be applied and the next line after `if`statement cannot be run. while the value (-10.000000) is same in both of them.
How can the problem be solved, so that `if`statement find them equal?

Comment: Please provide the full error trace, and try to give a [mcve] (which may be difficult in the instance as there is some IO involved) so that we can replicate the error and try to help.

Comment: Also, try to only ask one question at a time.  Asking two means you may not get any answer as somoene who can answer one part might not be bale to answer the other.

Comment: @Daniel F: The question was changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identical float values comparing as inequal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853323/identical-float-values-comparing-as-inequal)

Comment: The link couldn't be solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The values are actually not the same. `Slice_num[person][i, [1]]` is a numpy.ndarray containing one item, namely the value you want to compare. 
Try
`Slice_num[person][i, [1]][0] == Z_pos`

Comment: `Slice_num[person][i, [1]][0] == Z_pos` wasn't worked.                                               `Slice_num[person][i, [1]][0] = {str_} -10.000000` and `Z_pos = {DSfloat} -10.000000`. That is beacause of data structures.

Comment: Yes. so trying that suggestion gave you acces to the value you want. Now cast it to whichever type works for you :)